# Feature that works on android and not on ios in Flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a code in the Hello application that directs you to sms, it works on android without any problems, it does not work on ios

```
onPressed : () {
                      launch('sms:'+ widget.appointmentDetails.pPhn + '?body=Sayın ' + widget.appointmentDetails.pFirstName + ' ' + widget.appointmentDetails.pLastName + ' Merhaba. '
                          + widget.appointmentDetails.appointmentDate + ' Tarihinde ' +  widget.appointmentDetails.appointmentTime + ' Saatinde randevunuz olduğunu hatırlatır, keyifli günler dileriz' );

                    },
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

use URL_Launcher package

```
_msg() async {
    const uri = 'sms:+1231231231?body=hi';
    if (await canLaunch(uri)) {
      await launch(uri);
    } else {
      // iOS
      const uri = 'sms:+1231231231?body=hi';
      if (await canLaunch(uri)) {
        await launch(uri);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $uri';
      }
    }
  }
```